# Matrix Dantzig selector with many constraints

Tags: st.statistics, oc.optimization-and-control, compressed-sensing

We observe data from the model
$$
y_1=\mathcal{A}_1(X)+z_1\\
...\\
y_k=\mathcal{A}_k(X)+z_k\\
$$
where $X$ is an unknown $n\times n$ matrix with rank at most $r$, each $\mathcal{A}_i:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\mapsto \mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear mapping, and $\mathcal{A}^*_i$ is the adjoint
of $\mathcal{A}_i$.

$\sum_i \mathcal{A}_i$ is with restricted isometry property
$$
(1-\delta)||X||_2\leq ||\sum_i \mathcal{A}_i (X)||_2\leq (1+\delta)||X||_2
$$
for any $X$ with rank at most $r$.

Moreover, $\mathcal{A}_i\mathcal{A}_j=0$ for $i\neq j$.

We are interested in the following matrix Dantzig selector
$$
\mathrm{minimize}\ \ \  ||X||_*\\
\mathrm{subject\ \  to}\ \ \ \  ||\mathcal{A}^*_i(y_i-\mathcal{A}_i(X))||\leq \lambda_i \ \ \mathrm{for\ all} \ \ i.
$$
$||\cdot||_*$ denotes the nuclear norm, and $||\cdot||$ denotes the operator norm.

Suppose $y_i$s are sampled from $N$, and the solution of this matrix Dantzig selector is $M$, how can we bound the error
$$
||M-N||_2^2
$$
in term of $r$, $\lambda_i$s and $\delta$?

$O(r(\sum \lambda_i)^2)$ is easy to see.

It seems $O(r\sum \lambda_i^2)$ is not correct.
Is $O(n\sum \lambda_i^2)$ tight?

Comment: Is $M$ equal $X$? Also: What do you mean by "What can we have…"?

Comment: @Dirk Thank you very much! The typos are corrected. In the current version, $M$ is the solution for approximate $X$.

Comment: What are the input probability assumptions for the model? if there aren't any, how can the probability of anything be computed?

Comment: @Mark L. Stone Thank you very much! Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: What does $M - X$ mean? $M$ is the argmin of an optimization problem in which $X$ is the optimization variable, So what can $M - X$ mean in this context? Perhaps you have some concept of a "true" $X$, as opposed to the argmin of the optimization problem, which is $M$. But if this is the case, you need to tell us something about what that true $X$ is ir could be, and that perhaps brings up back to your now removed mention of probability. You need to make a clear, unambiguous statement of the problem.

Comment: @Mark L. Stone Thank you very much! I hope the current version is more clear.

Comment: You haven;t defined "true". I am not just being pedantic.

Comment: @Mark L. Stone Sure! I hope this is better.

Comment: What is the sampling distribution of $y_i$? The best and perhaps only way to get what you want might be by simulation. Perform m simulation replications. For each replications solve the optimization problem for the $y_i$ chosen for that replication.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone $\mathcal{A}^*_i(y_i-\mathcal{A}_i(X))||\leq \lambda_i$ are the only known conditions. The distribution of $y_i$ is not known.